# i can't run wpf app after install .net runtime in some windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I have project build in wpf code 3.1.0 .net and it's run on my machine perfectly but when i wanna install in
windows 7 : it can't run and cant install .net automatically and when i install .net manually it shows

```
The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer.  Try to reinstall the program to correct this problem.
```

and that happed to in some version of window 10 but when i install .net manually they don't work (don't even show any message).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#publish-a-single-file-app---cli

Comment: I use multiple project in the same solution , how can i publish all of them in one exe

Comment: You only need to publish the main executable (the one contains the `Main` method).

Comment: and how i can set this file  "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll"  in my project to remove the error in some versions of windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0dll/552e71e9-3ebc-409c-bbf3-4da46406c0b3) question for the "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll" error

Comment: thenx bro this help me in windows 7 and to understand the problem